# Adding trailing characters on a string based on some criteria of other variables?

Tags: python-2.7, loops, pandas

I am trying to manipulate the data via Python Pandas. However, I am not quite sure how to do this.

Imagine I have the name data, and each name has a corresponding string length. I want to create a new name variable in which I fill the current name variable with "?" up till it has 15 total characters.

For example:
Mike Miller will be converted into mike#miller???? and
G I Joe will be converted into g#i#joe????????

It seems the line below: frame3["name_filled"] = frame3["name"] + filler*"???" is not right, but I am not sure how to iterate within a single line based on two other variables.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import re

# Get csv file into data frame
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\OddNames_sampleData.csv")
frame = DataFrame(data)
frame.columns = ["name", "ethnicity"]
name = frame.name
ethnicity = frame.ethnicity

# Remove missing ethnicity data cases
index_missEthnic = frame.ethnicity.isnull()
index_missName = frame.name.isnull()
frame2 = frame.loc[~index_missEthnic, :]
frame3 = frame2.loc[~index_missName, :]

# Make all letters into lowercase
frame3.loc[:, "name"] = frame3["name"].str.lower()
frame3.loc[:, "ethnicity"] = frame3["ethnicity"].str.lower()

# Remove all non-alphabetical characters in Name
frame3.loc[:, "name"] = frame3["name"].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z\s\-]', '') # Retain space and hyphen

# Replace empty space as "#"
frame3.loc[:, "name"] = frame3["name"].str.replace('[\s]', '#')

# Find the longest name in the dataset
frame3["name_length"] = frame3["name"].str.len()
nameLength = frame3.name_length
frame3["filler"] = 15 - nameLength
filler = frame3.filler

# Add "?" to fill spaces up to 15 characters
frame3["name_filled"] = frame3["name"] + filler*"???"

# Test outputs
print frame3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method [`pad`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.pad.html#pandas.Series.str.pad):

```
In [2]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['asdasd','Fred','Ginger']})
df
Out[2]:
        a
0  asdasd
1    Fred
2  Ginger
In [6]:

df.a.str.pad(side='right',width=15,fillchar='?')
Out[6]:
0    asdasd?????????
1    Fred???????????
2    Ginger?????????
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: Any idea why I am getting this error? pad() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fillchar'

Comment: What version pandas are you using, mine is `0.16.0`

Comment: Actually this was a new feature in [0.16.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#string-methods-enhancements) can you upgrade?